# Unable to read POSTed application/json data in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app which has one endpoint as:

```
@app.route('/restaurant/<restaurant_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def detail(restaurant_id=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #something
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print jsonify(request.get_json(force=True)) #This doesn't work if I set content type as applicaiton/json
        comments = [request.form['comment']] #this works if I set content type as form-data
        # something
        return Response(json.dumps({
                'success': True,
                'response': json_docs
                }), status=200, content_type='application/json')
```

For some reason, I'm unable to read the POSTed data  when it is posted as a JSON with `application/json` as the `Content-Type`. The print command just returns `None`. How do I read the Json data?

Comment: Do you want to get the json data? `get_json()` should be enough, why use the `jsonify()`, it's usually used to create a response with the json representation.

Answer (score 0):

`request.get_json()` returns JSON, so `jsonify` should turn it back into JSON. And comments should be `request.get_json(force=True)`. Hope this helps.